# R convert dataframe string column to datetime with one-digit length hour

Tags: r, datetime, type-conversion, hour

How can I convert a "string" dataframe column `attr_date` into datetime when my hour can be one digit length too (eg.: `2012.01.01 9:00:00`)? The following code returns only with the date part without time part:

```
df[['attr_date']] <- as.Date(df[['attr_date']], format='%Y.%m.%d  %H:%M:%S')
```

So the result of `2012.01.01 9:00:00` is `2012-01-01`.

Bonus question:
Using Anaconda R Essentials, in Jupyter R Notebook why I get `15340.00` as the result of `2012.01.01 9:00:00` when I use the above code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `strptime` instead:

```
df[['attr_date']] <- strptime(df[['attr_date']], format='%Y.%m.%d  %H:%M:%S')
```